# Rematrix is needed between 10 channels and mono but there is not enough information to do it

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mono

I've been fighting for a number of days now trying to get FFmpeg working with combining several audio files at specific times into one file. So my idea was to generate silence up to the time i want to play a sound.Then merge the audio together with a filter. The below code works when I have five or less files, but seems to fall apart. What I'm trying

```
ffmpeg \
    -i "tutorial_bass/C-maj/TutorialBassJR.wav" \
    -i "tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsJR.wav" \
    -i "tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsTU.wav" \
    -i "tutorial_bass/C-maj/TutorialBassTU.wav" \
    -i "tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsTU.wav" \
    -i "tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsTD.wav" \
    -i "tutorial_bass/C-maj/TutorialBassTD.wav" \
    -i "tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsTD.wav" \
    -i "tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsTR.wav" \
    -i "tutorial_bass/C-maj/TutorialBassTR.wav" \
    -i "tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsTR.wav" \
    -i "tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsWL.wav" \
    -i "tutorial_bass/C-maj/TutorialBassWL.wav" \
    -i "tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsWL.wav" \
    -i "tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsWU.wav" \
    -i "tutorial_bass/C-maj/TutorialBassWU.wav" \
    -i "tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsWU.wav" \
    -i "tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsWD.wav" \
    -i "tutorial_bass/C-maj/TutorialBassWD.wav" \
    -i "tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsWD.wav" \
    -i "tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsJL.wav" \
    -i "tutorial_bass/C-maj/TutorialBassJL.wav" \
    -i "tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsJL.wav" \
    -i "tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsJR.wav" \
    -i "tutorial_bass/C-maj/TutorialBassJR.wav" \
    -i "tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsJR.wav" \
    -i "tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsJU.wav" \
    -i "tutorial_bass/C-maj/TutorialBassJU.wav" \
    -i "tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsJU.wav" \
    -i "tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsJD.wav" \
    -i "tutorial_bass/C-maj/TutorialBassJD.wav" \
    -i "tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsJD.wav" \
    -i "tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsTL.wav" \
    -i "tutorial_bass/C-maj/TutorialBassTL.wav" \
    -i "tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsTL.wav" \
    -i "tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsTR.wav" \
    -i "tutorial_bass/C-maj/TutorialBassTR.wav" \
    -i "tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsTR.wav" \
    -i "tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsTU.wav" \
    -i "tutorial_bass/C-maj/TutorialBassTU.wav" \
    -i "tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsTU.wav" \
    -i "tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsTD.wav" \
    -i "tutorial_bass/C-maj/TutorialBassTD.wav" \
    -i "tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsTD.wav" \
    -filter_complex "\
    aevalsrc=0:d=3.0  [d0];\
    aevalsrc=0:d=3.0  [d1];\
    aevalsrc=0:d=4.5  [d2];\
    aevalsrc=0:d=4.5  [d3];\
    aevalsrc=0:d=4.5  [d4];\
    aevalsrc=0:d=6.0  [d5];\
    aevalsrc=0:d=6.0  [d6];\
    aevalsrc=0:d=6.0  [d7];\
    aevalsrc=0:d=7.5  [d8];\
    aevalsrc=0:d=7.5  [d9];\
    aevalsrc=0:d=7.5  [d10];\
    aevalsrc=0:d=9.0  [d11];\
    aevalsrc=0:d=9.0  [d12];\
    aevalsrc=0:d=9.0  [d13];\
    aevalsrc=0:d=10.5 [d14];\
    aevalsrc=0:d=10.5 [d15];\
    aevalsrc=0:d=10.5 [d16];\
    aevalsrc=0:d=12.0 [d17];\
    aevalsrc=0:d=12.0 [d18];\
    aevalsrc=0:d=12.0 [d19];\
    aevalsrc=0:d=13.5 [d20];\
    aevalsrc=0:d=13.5 [d21];\
    aevalsrc=0:d=13.5 [d22];\
    aevalsrc=0:d=15.0 [d23];\
    aevalsrc=0:d=15.0 [d24];\
    aevalsrc=0:d=15.0 [d25];\
    aevalsrc=0:d=16.5 [d26];\
    aevalsrc=0:d=16.5 [d27];\
    aevalsrc=0:d=16.5 [d28];\
    aevalsrc=0:d=18.0 [d29];\
    aevalsrc=0:d=18.0 [d30];\
    aevalsrc=0:d=18.0 [d31];\
    aevalsrc=0:d=19.5 [d32];\
    aevalsrc=0:d=19.5 [d33];\
    aevalsrc=0:d=19.5 [d34];\
    aevalsrc=0:d=21.0 [d35];\
    aevalsrc=0:d=21.0 [d36];\
    aevalsrc=0:d=21.0 [d37];\
    aevalsrc=0:d=22.5 [d38];\
    aevalsrc=0:d=22.5 [d39];\
    aevalsrc=0:d=22.5 [d40];\
    aevalsrc=0:d=24.0 [d41];\
    aevalsrc=0:d=24.0 [d42];\
    aevalsrc=0:d=24.0 [d43];\
    [d0][0:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1   [a0];\
    [d1][1:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1   [a1];\
    [d2][2:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1   [a2];\
    [d3][3:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1   [a3];\
    [d4][4:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1   [a4];\
    [d5][5:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1   [a5];\
    [d6][6:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1   [a6];\
    [d7][7:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1   [a7];\
    [d8][8:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1   [a8];\
    [d9][9:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1   [a9];\
    [d10][10:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1 [a10];\
    [d11][11:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1 [a11];\
    [d12][12:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1 [a12];\
    [d13][13:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1 [a13];\
    [d14][14:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1 [a14];\
    [d15][15:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1 [a15];\
    [d16][16:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1 [a16];\
    [d17][17:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1 [a17];\
    [d18][18:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1 [a18];\
    [d19][19:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1 [a19];\
    [d20][20:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1 [a20];\
    [d21][21:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1 [a21];\
    [d22][22:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1 [a22];\
    [d23][23:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1 [a23];\
    [d24][24:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1 [a24];\
    [d25][25:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1 [a25];\
    [d26][26:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1 [a26];\
    [d27][27:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1 [a27];\
    [d28][28:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1 [a28];\
    [d29][29:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1 [a29];\
    [d30][30:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1 [a30];\
    [d31][31:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1 [a31];\
    [d32][32:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1 [a32];\
    [d33][33:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1 [a33];\
    [d34][34:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1 [a34];\
    [d35][35:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1 [a35];\
    [d36][36:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1 [a36];\
    [d37][37:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1 [a37];\
    [d38][38:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1 [a38];\
    [d39][39:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1 [a39];\
    [d40][40:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1 [a40];\
    [d41][41:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1 [a41];\
    [d42][42:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1 [a42];\
    [d43][43:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1 [a43];\
    [a0][a1][a2][a3][a4][a5][a6][a7][a8][a9][a10][a11][a12][a13][a14][a15][a16][a17][a18][a19]amix=inputs=20:duration=longest [a0-a19];\
    [a20][a21][a22][a23][a24][a25][a26][a27][a28][a29][a30][a31][a32][a33][a34][a35][a36][a37][a38][a39]amix=inputs=20:duration=longest [a20-a39];\
    [a40][a41][a42][a43]amix=inputs=4:duration=longest [a40-a43];
    [a0-a19][a20-a39][a40-a43]amix=inputs=3:duration=longest"  -codec:a libmp3lame output.mp3
```

When I run this command I get:

```
ffmpeg version 3.3.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.3.4 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --disable-lzma --enable-libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=jpeg2000 --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/Cellar/openjpeg/2.2.0/include/openjpeg-2.2 --enable-nonfree --enable-vda
  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
  libavresample   3.  5.  0 /  3.  5.  0
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, wav, from 'tutorial_bass/C-maj/TutorialBassJR.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:01.50, bitrate: 2822 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, stereo, flt, 2822 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #1.0 : stereo
Input #1, wav, from 'tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsJR.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:00.75, bitrate: 2822 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, stereo, flt, 2822 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #2.0 : stereo
Input #2, wav, from 'tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsTU.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:00.75, bitrate: 2822 kb/s
    Stream #2:0: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, stereo, flt, 2822 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #3.0 : stereo
Input #3, wav, from 'tutorial_bass/C-maj/TutorialBassTU.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:01.50, bitrate: 2822 kb/s
    Stream #3:0: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, stereo, flt, 2822 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #4.0 : stereo
Input #4, wav, from 'tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsTU.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:00.75, bitrate: 2822 kb/s
    Stream #4:0: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, stereo, flt, 2822 kb/s
Input #5, wav, from 'tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsTD.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:04.50, bitrate: 14112 kb/s
    Stream #5:0: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, 10 channels, flt, 14112 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #6.0 : stereo
Input #6, wav, from 'tutorial_bass/C-maj/TutorialBassTD.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:01.50, bitrate: 2822 kb/s
    Stream #6:0: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, stereo, flt, 2822 kb/s
Input #7, wav, from 'tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsTD.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:04.50, bitrate: 14112 kb/s
    Stream #7:0: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, 10 channels, flt, 14112 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #8.0 : stereo
Input #8, wav, from 'tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsTR.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:00.75, bitrate: 2822 kb/s
    Stream #8:0: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, stereo, flt, 2822 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #9.0 : stereo
Input #9, wav, from 'tutorial_bass/C-maj/TutorialBassTR.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:01.50, bitrate: 2822 kb/s
    Stream #9:0: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, stereo, flt, 2822 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #10.0 : stereo
Input #10, wav, from 'tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsTR.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:00.75, bitrate: 2822 kb/s
    Stream #10:0: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, stereo, flt, 2822 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #11.0 : stereo
Input #11, wav, from 'tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsWL.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:00.75, bitrate: 2822 kb/s
    Stream #11:0: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, stereo, flt, 2822 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #12.0 : stereo
Input #12, wav, from 'tutorial_bass/C-maj/TutorialBassWL.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:01.50, bitrate: 2822 kb/s
    Stream #12:0: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, stereo, flt, 2822 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #13.0 : stereo
Input #13, wav, from 'tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsWL.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:00.75, bitrate: 2822 kb/s
    Stream #13:0: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, stereo, flt, 2822 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #14.0 : stereo
Input #14, wav, from 'tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsWU.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:00.75, bitrate: 2822 kb/s
    Stream #14:0: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, stereo, flt, 2822 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #15.0 : stereo
Input #15, wav, from 'tutorial_bass/C-maj/TutorialBassWU.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:01.50, bitrate: 2822 kb/s
    Stream #15:0: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, stereo, flt, 2822 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #16.0 : stereo
Input #16, wav, from 'tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsWU.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:00.75, bitrate: 2822 kb/s
    Stream #16:0: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, stereo, flt, 2822 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #17.0 : stereo
Input #17, wav, from 'tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsWD.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:00.75, bitrate: 2822 kb/s
    Stream #17:0: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, stereo, flt, 2822 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #18.0 : stereo
Input #18, wav, from 'tutorial_bass/C-maj/TutorialBassWD.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:01.50, bitrate: 2822 kb/s
    Stream #18:0: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, stereo, flt, 2822 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #19.0 : stereo
Input #19, wav, from 'tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsWD.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:00.75, bitrate: 2822 kb/s
    Stream #19:0: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, stereo, flt, 2822 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #20.0 : stereo
Input #20, wav, from 'tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsJL.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:00.75, bitrate: 33869 kb/s
    Stream #20:0: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, stereo, flt, 2822 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #21.0 : stereo
Input #21, wav, from 'tutorial_bass/C-maj/TutorialBassJL.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:01.51, bitrate: 2822 kb/s
    Stream #21:0: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, stereo, flt, 2822 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #22.0 : stereo
Input #22, wav, from 'tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsJL.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:00.75, bitrate: 33869 kb/s
    Stream #22:0: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, stereo, flt, 2822 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #23.0 : stereo
Input #23, wav, from 'tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsJR.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:00.75, bitrate: 2822 kb/s
    Stream #23:0: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, stereo, flt, 2822 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #24.0 : stereo
Input #24, wav, from 'tutorial_bass/C-maj/TutorialBassJR.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:01.50, bitrate: 2822 kb/s
    Stream #24:0: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, stereo, flt, 2822 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #25.0 : stereo
Input #25, wav, from 'tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsJR.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:00.75, bitrate: 2822 kb/s
    Stream #25:0: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, stereo, flt, 2822 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #26.0 : stereo
Input #26, wav, from 'tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsJU.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:00.75, bitrate: 2822 kb/s
    Stream #26:0: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, stereo, flt, 2822 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #27.0 : stereo
Input #27, wav, from 'tutorial_bass/C-maj/TutorialBassJU.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:01.50, bitrate: 2822 kb/s
    Stream #27:0: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, stereo, flt, 2822 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #28.0 : stereo
Input #28, wav, from 'tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsJU.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:00.75, bitrate: 2822 kb/s
    Stream #28:0: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, stereo, flt, 2822 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #29.0 : stereo
Input #29, wav, from 'tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsJD.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:00.75, bitrate: 2822 kb/s
    Stream #29:0: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, stereo, flt, 2822 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #30.0 : stereo
Input #30, wav, from 'tutorial_bass/C-maj/TutorialBassJD.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:01.50, bitrate: 2822 kb/s
    Stream #30:0: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, stereo, flt, 2822 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #31.0 : stereo
Input #31, wav, from 'tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsJD.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:00.75, bitrate: 2822 kb/s
    Stream #31:0: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, stereo, flt, 2822 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #32.0 : stereo
Input #32, wav, from 'tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsTL.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:00.75, bitrate: 2822 kb/s
    Stream #32:0: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, stereo, flt, 2822 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #33.0 : stereo
Input #33, wav, from 'tutorial_bass/C-maj/TutorialBassTL.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:01.50, bitrate: 2822 kb/s
    Stream #33:0: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, stereo, flt, 2822 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #34.0 : stereo
Input #34, wav, from 'tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsTL.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:00.75, bitrate: 2822 kb/s
    Stream #34:0: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, stereo, flt, 2822 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #35.0 : stereo
Input #35, wav, from 'tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsTR.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:00.75, bitrate: 2822 kb/s
    Stream #35:0: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, stereo, flt, 2822 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #36.0 : stereo
Input #36, wav, from 'tutorial_bass/C-maj/TutorialBassTR.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:01.50, bitrate: 2822 kb/s
    Stream #36:0: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, stereo, flt, 2822 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #37.0 : stereo
Input #37, wav, from 'tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsTR.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:00.75, bitrate: 2822 kb/s
    Stream #37:0: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, stereo, flt, 2822 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #38.0 : stereo
Input #38, wav, from 'tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsTU.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:00.75, bitrate: 2822 kb/s
    Stream #38:0: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, stereo, flt, 2822 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #39.0 : stereo
Input #39, wav, from 'tutorial_bass/C-maj/TutorialBassTU.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:01.50, bitrate: 2822 kb/s
    Stream #39:0: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, stereo, flt, 2822 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #40.0 : stereo
Input #40, wav, from 'tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsTU.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:00.75, bitrate: 2822 kb/s
    Stream #40:0: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, stereo, flt, 2822 kb/s
Input #41, wav, from 'tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsTD.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:04.50, bitrate: 14112 kb/s
    Stream #41:0: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, 10 channels, flt, 14112 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #42.0 : stereo
Input #42, wav, from 'tutorial_bass/C-maj/TutorialBassTD.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:01.50, bitrate: 2822 kb/s
    Stream #42:0: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, stereo, flt, 2822 kb/s
Input #43, wav, from 'tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsTD.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:04.50, bitrate: 14112 kb/s
    Stream #43:0: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, 10 channels, flt, 14112 kb/s
File 'output.mp3' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (pcm_f32le) -> concat:in1:a0
  Stream #1:0 (pcm_f32le) -> concat:in1:a0
  Stream #2:0 (pcm_f32le) -> concat:in1:a0
  Stream #3:0 (pcm_f32le) -> concat:in1:a0
  Stream #4:0 (pcm_f32le) -> concat:in1:a0
  Stream #5:0 (pcm_f32le) -> concat:in1:a0
  Stream #6:0 (pcm_f32le) -> concat:in1:a0
  Stream #7:0 (pcm_f32le) -> concat:in1:a0
  Stream #8:0 (pcm_f32le) -> concat:in1:a0
  Stream #9:0 (pcm_f32le) -> concat:in1:a0
  Stream #10:0 (pcm_f32le) -> concat:in1:a0
  Stream #11:0 (pcm_f32le) -> concat:in1:a0
  Stream #12:0 (pcm_f32le) -> concat:in1:a0
  Stream #13:0 (pcm_f32le) -> concat:in1:a0
  Stream #14:0 (pcm_f32le) -> concat:in1:a0
  Stream #15:0 (pcm_f32le) -> concat:in1:a0
  Stream #16:0 (pcm_f32le) -> concat:in1:a0
  Stream #17:0 (pcm_f32le) -> concat:in1:a0
  Stream #18:0 (pcm_f32le) -> concat:in1:a0
  Stream #19:0 (pcm_f32le) -> concat:in1:a0
  Stream #20:0 (pcm_f32le) -> concat:in1:a0
  Stream #21:0 (pcm_f32le) -> concat:in1:a0
  Stream #22:0 (pcm_f32le) -> concat:in1:a0
  Stream #23:0 (pcm_f32le) -> concat:in1:a0
  Stream #24:0 (pcm_f32le) -> concat:in1:a0
  Stream #25:0 (pcm_f32le) -> concat:in1:a0
  Stream #26:0 (pcm_f32le) -> concat:in1:a0
  Stream #27:0 (pcm_f32le) -> concat:in1:a0
  Stream #28:0 (pcm_f32le) -> concat:in1:a0
  Stream #29:0 (pcm_f32le) -> concat:in1:a0
  Stream #30:0 (pcm_f32le) -> concat:in1:a0
  Stream #31:0 (pcm_f32le) -> concat:in1:a0
  Stream #32:0 (pcm_f32le) -> concat:in1:a0
  Stream #33:0 (pcm_f32le) -> concat:in1:a0
  Stream #34:0 (pcm_f32le) -> concat:in1:a0
  Stream #35:0 (pcm_f32le) -> concat:in1:a0
  Stream #36:0 (pcm_f32le) -> concat:in1:a0
  Stream #37:0 (pcm_f32le) -> concat:in1:a0
  Stream #38:0 (pcm_f32le) -> concat:in1:a0
  Stream #39:0 (pcm_f32le) -> concat:in1:a0
  Stream #40:0 (pcm_f32le) -> concat:in1:a0
  Stream #41:0 (pcm_f32le) -> concat:in1:a0
  Stream #42:0 (pcm_f32le) -> concat:in1:a0
  Stream #43:0 (pcm_f32le) -> concat:in1:a0
  amix -> Stream #0:0 (libmp3lame)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[auto_resampler_5 @ 0x7fdc19641e00] [SWR @ 0x7fdc1c286e00] Rematrix is needed between 10 channels and mono but there is not enough information to do it
[auto_resampler_5 @ 0x7fdc19641e00] Failed to configure output pad on auto_resampler_5
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #43:0
Conversion failed!
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or other approaches I could take to do this?

Comment: Are there any sets of audio inputs which don't overlap with each other?

Comment: Not necessarily, I'm trying to rebuild a song from the different sounds contained in the audio files. So I have to stitch together those files at specific times

Comment: I also tried using the pan filter to explicitly call the input mono or audio...and the command worked....I just had no sound and wasn't the appropriate length; so idk what really happened

Answer (score 2):

So I found the solution to my problem. I assumed that the number of files or something was increasing the number of channels. Turns out there was just one Bizarre wav file in the mix that had 10 mono channels, and ffmpeg was not having it. Opening Audacity and removing all of the other channels solved the problem.

Below was the input line I should have paid attention to earlier

```
Input #43, wav, from 'tutorial_drums/TutorialDrumsTD.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:04.50, bitrate: 14112 kb/s
    Stream #43:0: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, 10 channels, flt, 14112 kb/s
File 'output.mp3' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
```